# Finiding multiple objects at a time by using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to find both objects at a time by using selenium web driver in Java.

Comment: you could use `and`

Comment: Can you show your code or html snippet for better context.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please elaborate on what you are trying to do and add the relevant code/html.

Comment: Actually the question was asked in an interview that how would you find both the objects at a time. i was a fresher for selenium.@guy @rao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID's and xpath's are unique for each element in HTML.
You can choose other options like
1) cssSelector
2) CLASS
3) TAGNAME
4) Link

You can to create a data structure like link to store all the elements.
Example:

WebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();
List options= driver.findElements(By.tagName("p"));

Comment: can we use any java script executor two find two elements. @Anand

Comment: Sure. You can use "document.getElementsByClassName " method. But you have to care about browser compatibility for the javascript methods.